# Facebook like button behaves differently when liked and not liked

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Facebook 'Like' button on my page:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"/>
```

I also have the `'fb-root'` div and the SDK `javascript` (the button functions just as it should).

For some reason, when the like button is toggled on (occurs when the visitor is connected to his Facebook account AND had already liked my page before) the button will magically reduce its width (in some last second javascript) and make the other buttons (twitter/g+) hide it. It aligns just fine for a second and then 'collapses'.

I tried disabling my css and many other components of my site, to no avail.
I attached an image illustrating the situation.

EDIT: Something I just found out. The width attribute is the one that seems to be overridden. When setting `width = 2000` (rediculusly high), when the like button is enabled (user is not connected/not liked), the button is indeed `2000px` wide, but when a previously-liked user is connected, you can see the 2000px width for a second there, and then it 'collapses' again.

EDIT2: I seem to have found the culprit, but I don't know why and how to fix it. It seems the generated code in the toggled on facebook button sets the width to 72 instead of 100.

Generated code for enabled button:

```
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://mysite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial">
<span style="height: 20px; width: 100px;">
```

Generated code for liked(diabled) button:

```
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://mysite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial">
<span style="height: 21px; width: 72px;">
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up adding this to my CSS:

```
div.fb-like > span {
min-width:100px;
}
```

Probably not the best way, but it is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use

```
<div style="width: 100px;"></div>
```

to wrap around your code. usually the plugin will automatically adapt to the width of its parent element on page load.

If the width of parent element is smaller than your data-width, it could cause your Facebook button to shrink. This could be the reason why your button size changes.